# How to join ids from an xml stored in a column with ids from a column in another table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I try to join a list of ids from a xml stored in a column with ids from a column in another table. How can I extract them to get the matching rows.

I cant change the table. The schema can be reduced as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE abc([Data] [ntext] NOT NULL, [Group] varchar(3));
INSERT INTO abc
    ([Data], [Group])
VALUES
    ('<div>
     <test name="Test1" enabled="True"/>
     <ul>
     <i><a id="t.foo"/></i>
     <i><a id="t.bar"/></i>
     </ul>
    </div>', 'ADG')
;
GO

CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    ([productName] varchar(13), [description] varchar(57), [Group] varchar(3))

INSERT INTO ForgeRock ([productName], [description], [Group])
VALUES
    ('foo', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions', 'ADG'),
    ('bar', 'Full-featured access management', 'ADG'),
    ('taz', 'Robust LDAP server for Java', 'ADG')
;
```

And here is the query I wrote:

```sql
SELECT
      [productName]
      , [description]
  FROM ForgeRock
 INNER JOIN abc on ForgeRock.[Group] = abc.[Group]
 WHERE cast(abc.[Data] as xml).exist('//div/test[@name="Test1" and @enabled="True"]') = 1
  AND ('t.' + productName) LIKE ('%' + cast(abc.[Data] as xml).value('(//ul/i/a/@id)[1]', 'varchar(50)') + '%')
```

I know that the problem come from the last line, but I am not sure how to tackle the problem.

The actual output is:

```
productName     description
foo             Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions
```

But the expected output should be:

```
productName     description
foo             Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions
bar             Full-featured access management
```

I tried two solutions from SO (no they are not duplicated as far as I tried):

- [XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940566/xquery-value-value-requires-a-singleton-or-empty-sequence-found-oper)
- [Extracting Attributes from XML Fields in SQL Server 2008 Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846990/extracting-attributes-from-xml-fields-in-sql-server-2008-table)

[Try it Online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60871/13)

Comment: Why are you storing XML data in a `ntext` column? `ntext` has been deprecated since 2005; fix the data type.

Comment: @Larnu Well I am not if it is directly related to my question or not, but the answer is it is a legacy table. I wont change it right now, but I may look into it later on. What would be the best data type to host xml?

Comment: *"What would be the best data type to host xml?"* the aptly named `xml` datatype.

Comment: Disregarding your datatype woes, I don't understand the problem here, you're comparing `t.foo` with the first <a> item in the <ul><i> element, so you're getting what you asked for. To get the results you want you would need to also match on `LIKE ('%' + CAST(a.[Data] AS XML).value('(//ul/i/a/@id)[2]', 'varchar(50)') + '%'`

Comment: @RichardHansell I dont know how many ids the xml contained. It can be far more than 2.

Comment: @Larnu Well the name is fitting indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use `STUFF` to remove the 2 leading characters, and then compare, rather than a `LIKE`. I also, for my tests, have changed the data type of the column `Data` to `xml` as it is storing XML data, and `ntext` has been deprecated for 15~ years:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ForgeRock FR
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.abc a
                   CROSS APPLY a.[Data].nodes('/div/ul/i/a') i(a)
              WHERE STUFF(i.a.value('@id','varchar(15)'),1,2,'') = FR.productName);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf6839aeea27cdd9905cb4fa4c1acd2b)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I just posted one to a MCVE too. I will try this solution on my case and check if it works for me.

Comment: Cant I cast or convert into `CROSS APPLY`? `(cast(be.[Data] as xml)).nodes(` yields `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.`  and `(CONVERT(xml,be.[Data])).nodes(` yields `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.` I can change ntext right now.

Comment: You would have to use a table value construct, @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com l you can't just `APPLY` to a scalar function. This is why I suggest fixing the design.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

I used `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data type instead of `NTEXT`. You may need to adjust the final`SELECT` clause columns to accommodate your needs. I picked all of them just to show the all column values.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @abc TABLE (xmldata NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, [Group] CHAR(3));
INSERT INTO @abc (xmldata, [Group]) VALUES
(N'<div>
    <test name="Test1" enabled="True"/>
    <ul>
        <i>
            <a id="t.foo"/>
        </i>
        <i>
            <a id="t.bar"/>
        </i>
    </ul>
</div>', 'ADG');

DECLARE @ForgeRock TABLE ([productName] VARCHAR(13), [description] VARCHAR(57), [Group] char(3));
INSERT INTO @ForgeRock ([productName], [description], [Group]) VALUES
('foo', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions', 'ADG'),
('bar', 'Full-featured access management', 'ADG'),
('taz', 'Robust LDAP server for Java', 'ADG');

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT [Group], TRY_CAST(xmldata AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @abc
)
SELECT rs.[Group], c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS id
    , f.*
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('div[test[@name="Test1" and @enabled="True"]]/ul/i/a/@id') AS t(c)
    INNER JOIN @ForgeRock AS f ON rs.[Group] = f.[Group]
        AND SUBSTRING(c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)'), 3, 100) = f.productName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty straightforward approach:

```
DECLARE @abc table ( [Data] [ntext] NOT NULL, [Group] varchar(3) );
INSERT INTO @abc ( [Data], [Group] ) VALUES
    ( '<div><test name="Test1" enabled="True"/><ul><i><a id="t.foo"/></i><i><a id="t.bar"/></i></ul></div>', 'ADG' );

DECLARE @ForgeRock table ( [productName] varchar(13), [description] varchar(57), [Group] varchar(3) );
INSERT INTO @ForgeRock ( [productName], [description], [Group] ) VALUES
    ('foo', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions', 'ADG'),
    ('bar', 'Full-featured access management', 'ADG'),
    ('taz', 'Robust LDAP server for Java', 'ADG');

SELECT
    [productName], [description], x.f.value( '@id', 'VARCHAR(13)' ) AS id
FROM @ForgeRock ForgeRock
INNER JOIN @abc abc 
    ON ForgeRock.[Group] = abc.[Group]
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT CAST( abc.[data] AS xml ) AS x ) cx
CROSS APPLY cx.x.nodes( 'div[test[@name="Test1" and @enabled="True"]]/ul/i/a' ) x(f)
WHERE
    x.f.value( '@id', 'VARCHAR(13)' ) LIKE '%' + productName + '%';
```

Returns

```
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| productName |                       description                       |  id   |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| foo         | Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions | t.foo |
| bar         | Full-featured access management                         | t.bar |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Optionally, you can pass your `@name` value in as a SQL variable:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(50) = 'Test1';

SELECT
    [productName], [description], x.f.value( '@id', 'VARCHAR(13)' ) AS id
FROM @ForgeRock ForgeRock
INNER JOIN @abc abc 
    ON ForgeRock.[Group] = abc.[Group]
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT CAST( abc.[data] AS xml ) AS x ) cx
CROSS APPLY cx.x.nodes( 'div[test[@name=sql:variable("@name") and @enabled="True"]]/ul/i/a' ) x(f)
WHERE
    x.f.value( '@id', 'VARCHAR(13)' ) LIKE '%' + productName + '%';
```